# Degree of curves is stable in parametrized families

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let X , Y be projective varieties, and $C$ be a projective smooth curve. Suppose $f : C \times Y \to X$ is a morphism such that $\forall~ y \in Y$, $ f(-,y): C \to X$ does not contract $C$ to a point. Fix a very ample divisor $H$ in $X$, why $\forall~ y \in Y$, the intersection number $C \cdot f(-,y)^*H$ is a constant?

Comment: Dear Li Yutong, How does $C \cdot f^* H$ depend on $y$?  Regards,

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity at at this point, I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(-,y)^*H$ is just a divisor on $C$, I guess by $C \cdot f(-,y)^*H$ you just mean the degree of this divisor.

This is the same as the intersection number $(C \times y) \cdot f^*H,$ and so the question is why is this intersection number constant?  Well, it is an integer valued function that depends continuously on the parameter $y$, and so it must be constant (assuming that $Y$ is connected; if $Y$ were disconnected, then it wouldn't need to be constant).

A more formal way of phrasing this is to note that all the curves $C \times y$ on the variety $C \times Y$ are algebraically equivalent, and intersection number is invariant under algebraic equivalence of cycles.

Comment: Thank you very much! What theorem did you use that "$(C \times y)\cdot f^*H$ depends continuously on $y$"? I only know it has to be semi-continuously. Besides, as you mentioned that $C\times y$ are algebraically equivalent, I do see this statement somewhere, but still, I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Besides, I realized that the algebraically equivalent statement can be reduced to the case to prove : $Y$ is an one dimensional variety, then for any $y_1, y_2 \in Y, C \times y_1, C \times y_2$ are algebraically equivalent in $C \times Y$.