# $C \times y_1, C \times y_2$ are numerically equivalent in $C \times Y$ for curve $C$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

This question comes from my former [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480953/degree-of-curves-is-stable-in-parametrized-families).

Let me formulate the question more precisely.

Let $C$ be a projective smooth curve over an algebraically closed field. Let $Y$ be any variety. Why for any closed point $y_1,y_2 \in Y$, $C \times y_1, C \times y_2$ are numerically equivalent in $C\times Y$ ? Here, numerically equivalence means they have same intersection number for any curve.

One can reduce the above case to the case where dimensional of $Y$ is $1$.

Comment: Dear Yutong, the definition you give is for rational equivalence. That $C\times y_1$ is [algebraically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequate_equivalence_relation#Examples_of_equivalence_relations) to $C\times y_2$ is just because there is a connected curve in $Y$ passing through $y_1, y_2$.

Comment: Oh... I see. Is there any way to show algebraically equivalent implies numerically equivalent?(this should be true from the wikipedia page you gave.)

Comment: Roughly speaking, for any curve $E$, $E.(C\times \{y\})$ varies continuously in $y$ and takes integer values, so it is constant if $Y$ is connected.

Comment: @Cantlog But I worry that subtle things might happen, like self intersection.

Comment: The intersection number depends only on the rational equivalence class of $E$, and you can use moving lemma to avoid embarrassing situations. Anyway, you should be able to find a correct proof in Fulton's "Intersection Theory".